# wp mysql query find post types by another post type

Tags: mysql, wordpress

first time asking, so be gentile.

My problem is the admin search in wordpress. I need to find a custom post type based not only if the search term is found on it, but also same custom post type based if that search term is found on another custom post type that the first one is related to.

If someone is not familiar with wordpress database structure, here's an image of it with relationships:
[image]

I will use just wp_posts and wp_postmeta

So I need to find all **coupons** from wp_posts that have 'lorem' text in title or content ->

```
`post_type` LIKE 'coupon' AND (`post_title` LIKE '%lorem%' OR `post_content` LIKE '%lorem%')
```

But I also have in wp_posts custom post type **merchant** that is related to **coupons** in wp_postmeta where `post_id` is coupon id, `meta_key` is 'merchant' and `meta_value` is a serialized value like a:1:{i:0;s:4:"3249";} where 3249 is merchant id . (I know, it's weird).

So I need to somehow find out what merchants have, find their related coupons and then those coupons to be added in the initial query:

```
`post_type` LIKE 'merchant' AND (`post_title` LIKE '%lorem%' OR `post_content` LIKE '%lorem%')
```

I have managed to find a way, but it takes to long

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts. * 
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm 
    ON wp_posts.ID = pm.post_id
RIGHT JOIN wp_posts AS p2 
    ON pm.meta_value LIKE CONCAT(  '%a:1:{i:0;s:', LENGTH( p2.ID ) ,  ':"', p2.ID,  '";}%' ) 
WHERE 
    ( wp_posts.post_title LIKE  '%lorem%'       
    OR p2.post_title LIKE  '%lorem%'
    OR p2.post_content LIKE  '%lorem%'
    OR wp_posts.post_content LIKE  '%lorem%'
    )
AND wp_posts.post_type =  'coupon'
AND p2.post_type =  'merchant'
AND pm.meta_key =  'merchant'
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE  '%lorem%' DESC , wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

for 7 results it takes 1.6027 sec.

Thanks in advance

Comment: LEFT/RIGHT joins are totally irrelevant as you are then checking columns from all 3 tables in WHERE clause, so any row which would get NULLs from outer join will be excluded at that point. Just changing them to inner join might help optimizer pick a better plan in some cases. Please add [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) results for your query. And `SHOW CREATE TABLE ..` for tables used.

Comment: Sorry but the comment form doesn't let me to input much text, so I link them [EXPLAIN](http://cdrz.tk/wp-mysql-query-find-post-types-by-another-post-type/explaing.jpg) , [CREATE TABLES](http://cdrz.tk/wp-mysql-query-find-post-types-by-another-post-type/show_create_table.jpg)  and sql for create tables if you need to [wp_postmeta](http://cdrz.tk/wp-mysql-query-find-post-types-by-another-post-type/create_table_wp_postmeta.sql) and [wp_posts](http://cdrz.tk/wp-mysql-query-find-post-types-by-another-post-type/create_table_wp_posts.sql)

Comment: From the explain it has to check ~750K rows to return those 7. It cannot know better statistics as you search using LIKE. And the join using LIKE CONCAT is really bad for anything :(

Comment: So no tweaks to speed that query up or just another alternative? I had two more ideas, but I don't know mysql that much. 1. I was thinking of search separately and then join those results, but that will give me headaches on pagination/filters , or 2. to add in that sql a list of results and get them in a separate sql, but don't know if it's possible (like a join but with results all ready in there)... Or... I can right join parts of tables to make a single 'table

Comment: Or... I can right join parts of tables to make a single 'table' and have two `post_title` and two `post_content` , one from each post type, and search in those with a **OR** statement

Comment: You can not use covering index as `post_title` and `post_content` (and some others used) are text columns.. These are best searched using fulltext indexes.

Comment: @codernize - Sorry, old reply / slightly off topic. What tool did you use to build your DB diagrams?

Comment: @Steven it's a pic I found online